# Is this a dative of reference? Can it be translated as "of?'

Tags: dative

Text is (for context):

Segregatio autem vel evocatio haec, electio sive selectio appellatur duplici fere de causa: vel, quia e communi hominum caetu populi saepe nonnulli aliis quibusdam certo consilio divino praeteritis et relictis, uti in "electione" proprie dicta fieri solet, evocantur et quasi eximuntur ad audiendum, et sic ad participandum Evangelii gratiam singularem, **sive evocationi illi divinae morem gerant**

This separation or summoning, election or choice is generally deemed (such) from a twofold cause: either, because some from the common mass of the human race, by a fixed divine counsel, are summoned and removed from those who have been abandoned and passed by to hearing and partaking of the special grace of the Gospel; this is usually taken as election properly speaking, **or that they might assume the conduct to that divine call**.

Can this be taken instead as, "they they might assume the conduct of that divine call?"

Answer (score 4):

*Mos* in this context means *will, bidding*, and *alicui morem gerere* means *to do someone's bidding* (or even to *submit yourself to someone's will*). It is a fixed expression, usually found in the dictionary under [mos](https://www.latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries?t=lsn29755). I think it is a rather normal dative; *morem gerere* is what is done for the benefit of someone else.

Any attempt to connect the *sive* to the preceding sentence is bound for failure, because, as we can see when we [look at the original text](https://books.google.de/books?id=fHdmAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA2), it goes like this:

> … gratiam singularem; (sive evocationi illi morem gerant, ut 1. Cor. 1.26.27. Sive ad obediendum Euangelio tantum invitentur etc. etc. …) vel quia …